# How to pass username and password to paypal and get it back once payment is done

Tags: php, html, paypal

Imagine the following scenario:

1. User fills out the username and password and clicks Pay with Paypal button.
2. It is taken to Paypal where payment is done.
3. Now the Paypal says the the user with ID has completed transaction. this  id is generated by paypal.
4. At this point the website owner should link Paypal ID with the username and password previously filled out. For that to happen I need to send username and password to the Paypal in the first place.

My question is, how can I do that securely?

I am aware of custom paypal variable, but this variable is send as a query string in the href attribute of the paypal pay link.

What is the common way of solving this issue? Can you send password and username in GET request if your website is using HTTPS?

Comment: [Use a nonce](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/the-word-of-the-day-is-nonce.html).

Comment: thanks, I will look that up. One more question just popped..Can you send password and username in GET request if your website is using HTTPS?

Comment: No, don't do that. Ever.

Comment: Oh, i thought that is only for http. Thanks a lot. So basically  if I use  javascript to perform a hash and send username with hashed password to the paypal in URL and store that hashed value, that solves the issue. But on login attempt, the password is send as a clear text POST variable, and then hashed on the server to see if hashes match. Would that work?

Comment: @Martin The domain (via the `Host` header) is visible, but the full URL is not - it's part of the encrypted payload. The bigger concern is stuff like server logs, browser history, etc. with params in GET.

Comment: @ceejayoz ah, I knew it was something like that, I made a mental note to myself to assume the URL is unencrypted... and that mental note was what I was commenting from, but the real life details slip past me in my old age! `:-/`

Comment: @Martin No biggie. The take-away is still correct - no sensitive data in URLs. Even though it's encrypted in transit, it might still wind up in Google Analytics, log files, etc.